# Comparing output from Rcapture() with glm()

Tags: generalized-linear-model, capture-mark-recapture

I'm looking again at R's `Rcapture` package using the example given in https://hrdag.org/tech-notes/basic-mse.html and mirroring the results in a standard GLM. There are four columns samples in my data A, B, C and D and the best `RCapture` fit is [34,1,2]. Fitting this by

```
glm(Freq ~ C*D + A+B, family = poisson(link="log"),data=.)
```

almost works, the AIC is close, but is out by one degree of freedom. I'm sure `Rcapture` is right, but it gives a different answer to the GLM. From `Rcapture` I get for the first model or row in the output table

```
Number of captured units: 1530 

Abundance estimations and model fits for the models with the smallest BIC:
             abundance stderr deviance df     AIC     BIC infoFit
[34,1,2]        2330.8  137.2   19.738  8 106.025 143.356      OK
```

but one more residual d.f. from the GLM

```
Call:  glm(formula = Freq ~ C * D + A + B, family = poisson(link = "log"), 
    data = deaths)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            C            D            A            B          C:D  
     6.5111      -1.8288       0.4090      -2.3261      -2.7690      -0.5358  

Degrees of Freedom: 14 Total (i.e. Null);  9 Residual
  (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
```

Given that the R in both cases is most likely correct, what is my statistical error in my application of log-linear modelling to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the [example](https://hrdag.org/tech-notes/basic-mse.html) compelling, so after reading it I took a look at the [J. Stat. Softw. paper](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v019i05) that describes models implemented in the *Rcapture* package.

All *Rcapture* models have a component to account for heterogeneity in capture probabilities.

You are trying to reproduce the Poisson $M_t$ model since you are using the *closedpMS.t* function with *h = "Poisson"* option. The *t* subscript denotes temporal effect: the capture probabilities to vary among captures (these are the A, B, C and D variables).

For this model, the heterogeneity column in the design matrix is $2^{\sum\omega_j} - 1$. If you add this column to the data and the formula, you will reproduce the deviance, the residual degrees of freedom and the AIC. (The BIC is different though. Why?)

---

*Update* about the BIC. I figured out how Rcapture computes it though I don't understand yet why it is computed this way. Maybe it could be a follow-up question.

We know that the formula for the BIC is *-2 x log_likelihood + log(sample_size) x num_parameters*. The difference between the BIC reported by *glm* and the BIC reported by *Rcapture* boils down to what's the sample size.

```r
# Data from the HRDAG org
library("Rcapture")

A <- c(rep(0, 8), rep(1, 8))
B <- rep(c(rep(0, 4), rep(1, 4)), 2)
C <- c(rep(c(0, 0, 1, 1), 4))
D <- c(rep(c(0, 1), 8))

# killings in Guatemala's Ixil counties, April 1982 - July 1983
# NB: these are *all killings*, NOT filtered by perpetrator
Freq <- c(NA, 1021, 104, 94, 55, 54, 2, 4, 53, 98, 19, 11, 4, 8, 1, 2)
deaths <- as.data.frame(cbind(A, B, C, D, Freq))

fit1 <- closedpMS.t(deaths, dfreq = TRUE, h = "Poisson")
fit1
#> 
#> Number of captured units: 1530 
#> 
#> Abundance estimations and model fits for the models with the smallest BIC:
#>              abundance stderr deviance df     AIC     BIC infoFit
#> [34,1,2]        2330.8  137.2   19.738  8 106.025 143.356      OK

num_captures <- A + B + C + D
deaths$heterogeneity <- 2^(num_captures) - 1

fit2 <- glm(
  Freq ~ C * D + A + B + heterogeneity,
  family = poisson,
  data = deaths
)
broom::glance(fit2)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 8
#>   null.deviance df.null logLik   AIC   BIC deviance df.residual  nobs
#>           <dbl>   <int>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>       <int> <int>
#> 1         4233.      14  -46.0  106.  111.     19.7           8    15
```

Now let's compute the BIC, two ways.

```r
# The first frequency is NA. It corresponds to the un-captured individuals.
y <- Freq[-1]
mu <- fit2$fitted.values

# The log-likelihood is Poisson.
log_likelihood <- sum(dpois(y, mu, log = TRUE))

N <- sum(y) # number of captured individuals
n <- length(y) # number of capture "histories"
k <- length(fit2$coefficients) # number of model parameters

-2 * log_likelihood + log(n) * k # GLM BIC
#> [1] 110.9813
-2 * log_likelihood + log(N) * k # Rcapture BIC
#> [1] 143.3561
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. It was really useful and I need to go and follow up in the paper to learn more about their approach. There is still a slight difference (I get and abundance of about 2234 compared to their 2331) but at least the log-linear model does make sense but the paper is a good place to start.